# Split XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file which have multiple messages in one large file, my objective it to split the file into singe xml file for each message, I have a c# code which only gets me the first instance of the message. can you please tell what am I missing here:

Here is my code :

```
      string strSeq;
      string strFileName;
      XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\XMl\MR.xml");
      var newDocs = doc.Descendants("Message")
               .Select(d => new XDocument(new XElement("FileDump", d)));
             foreach (var newDoc in newDocs)
              {
               strSeq = XDocument.Load(@"C:\XMl\MR.xml").XPathSelectElement
               "//FileDump/Message/MsgID").Value;           

                strFileName = "MR_" + strSeq + ".xml";
                newDoc.Save(Console.Out); Console.WriteLine();
                newDoc.Save(@"C:\xml\MR\Tst\" + strFileName);
                Console.WriteLine();
               }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search for message ID within `newDoc` instead of `doc`:

```
foreach (var newDoc in newDocs)
{
    strSeq = newDoc.XPathSelectElement("//FileDump/Message/MsgID").Value;           

    strFileName = "MR_" + strSeq + ".xml";
    newDoc.Save(Console.Out); Console.WriteLine();
    newDoc.Save(@"C:\xml\MR\Tst\" + strFileName);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Marcins:when I changed the line to look for message it within the newdoc I get the following error:Cannot convert method group 'XPathSelectElement' to non-delegate type 'string'. This is the error I get when I modified the code to yours

Comment: @MoeR `(` missing. Try now.

Comment: @MoeR You're welcome! You should consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem. This is how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
string path = @"C:\xml\MR\Tst\MR_";

XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
foreach(XElement message in root.Descendants("Message"))
{
    string id = message.Element("MsgID").Value;
    message.Save(path + id + ".xml");
}
```